# What tools and software do writers use to write Wikipedia-style articles for website content?

Tags: technical-writing, software, tools

I want to understand the workflow in regard to professional writing career.

This is regarding writing detailed articles (non-fiction) on various subjects that also involve HTML tables (for tabular data), charts/diagrams, photos something like Wikipedia-style articles but not for Wikipedia. What tools do professional writers use for this purpose?

The goal is to make the process of articles written by the author easy to  save in a database and easily published online (HTML format). The nature of the article involves extensive research and collection of information to compose an article. So this also involves maintaining some sort of journal log.

Comment: you probably want a CMS like Drupal or Joomla, or even WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is probably a good solution. I just wanted to add that saving tabular data in a well known spreadsheet program is helpful for archiving. If you want to make tables on wordpress, try the Tablepress module; it's great.

My workflow may be strange, but I use Dropbox for version control, keep data and graphics in separate folders,  edit stuff in a simple text editor (Sublime Text, Notetab Pro, etc) and then transfer it to a rich text editor when I'm ready to finalize the presentation. For writing and collaboration, you don't necessarily need a database to store your data, but it's crucial to use a cloud solution like Dropbox -- which is very collaboration friendly. (A tip though -- free versions of cloud apps like dropbox have limited version control -- for Dropbox free, you only have versions from  30 days back).